# Adding New Records from one table with existing and new records to another table in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to to append data to a table that contains all the data up to this point. Every week I will be pulling in the new data (which will contain data already existing in the All table) and adding the new records. I added a few test data to the temp table where the generic, material num, etc. are all different but when I run this query it still says it is adding 0 records. Please help.

```
INSERT INTO ExtWafersAll ( generic, [material number], description, vendor, [net price], [std price], NumberOfDups )
    SELECT
            ExtWafersTemp.generic,
            ExtWafersTemp.[material number],
            ExtWafersTemp.description,
            ExtWafersTemp.vendor,
            ExtWafersTemp.[net price],
            ExtWafersTemp.[std price],
            ExtWafersTemp.NumberOfDups
        FROM ExtWafersTemp
        RIGHT JOIN ExtWafersAll
            ON (ExtWafersAll.NumberOfDups = ExtWafersTemp.NumberOfDups)
                AND (ExtWafersAll.[std price] = ExtWafersTemp.[std price])
                AND (ExtWafersAll.[net price] = ExtWafersTemp.[net price])
                AND (ExtWafersAll.vendor = ExtWafersTemp.vendor)
                AND (ExtWafersAll.description = ExtWafersTemp.description)
                AND (ExtWafersAll.[material number] = ExtWafersTemp.[material number])
                AND (ExtWafersAll.generic = ExtWafersTemp.generic)
        WHERE
            ExtWafersTemp.vendor <> ExtWafersAll.vendor
            OR ExtWafersTemp.description <> ExtWafersAll.description
            OR ExtWafersTemp.[material number] <> ExtWafersAll.[material number]
            OR ExtWafersTemp.generic <> ExtWafersAll.generic;
```

So for example in ExtWafersTemp we have:

```
Generic   Material Number     Description     Vendor     Net Price     Std Price  
j2151     sjkdga215           xxx125125       TMA        12            14   
asdg      asgasg              aggsggs         asg        15            18
```

And then in ExtWafersAll:

```
Generic   Material Number     Description     Vendor     Net Price     Std Price  
j2151     sjkdga215           xxx125125       TMA        12            14
```

I can't figure out how to add the new record thats in the temp to the all file

Comment: Your select query brings lines ?

Comment: please include some sample data from `ExtWafersTemp` and `ExtWafersAll` (data where you are under the impression "it should work", but do not see why it does not) so we can reproduce your issue

Comment: Is there a key defined for ExtWafersAll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would suit your need:

```
insert into ExtWafersAll ( generic, [material number], description, vendor, [net price], [std price], NumberOfDups )
select generic, [material number], description, vendor, [net price], [std price], NumberOfDups
from ExtWafersTemp
except
select generic, [material number], description, vendor, [net price], [std price], NumberOfDups
from ExtWafersAll;
```

In above snippet you add records from ExtWafersTemp table which are not present in ExtWafersAll table. Is this what are you trying to achieve?

About "except" operator you could read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29

UPDATE

As it occurred to be MS Access problem you could try to test this:

```
SELECT
  ExtWafersTemp.generic,
  ExtWafersTemp.[material number],
  ExtWafersTemp.description,
  ExtWafersTemp.vendor,
  ExtWafersTemp.[net price],
  ExtWafersTemp.[std price],
  ExtWafersTemp.NumberOfDups
FROM ExtWafersAll RIGHT JOIN ExtWafersTemp 
ON (ExtWafersAll.NumberOfDups = ExtWafersTemp.NumberOfDups
    AND ExtWafersAll.[std price] = ExtWafersTemp.[std price]
    AND ExtWafersAll.[net price] = ExtWafersTemp.[net price]
    AND ExtWafersAll.vendor = ExtWafersTemp.vendor
    AND ExtWafersAll.description = ExtWafersTemp.description
    AND ExtWafersAll.[material number] = ExtWafersTemp.[material number]
    AND ExtWafersAll.generic = ExtWafersTemp.generic)
WHERE ExtWafersAll.NumberOfDups is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.[std price] is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.[net price] is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.vendor is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.description is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.[material number] is null
  AND ExtWafersAll.generic is null
```

Genarally it is a following pattern (in example there is a primary key field - id):

```
select tt.id
from tableall t right join tabletemp tt 
  on (t.id = tt.id)
where t.id is null
```

Hope that it helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do except when i try to use your snippet in Access I'm getting errors

Comment: @user3669092 What errors do you get? Firstly try only select part (without insert line) to check whether you get correct rows. Then if it is ok, it would be most probably matter of syntax I suppose.

Comment: Btw, I don't know whether it is under your control, but using spaces inside column names is not the best idea.

Comment: it tells me there is an error in the FROM clause and highlights the SELECT statement after EXCEPT, and you are correct it is outside my control

Comment: Then check both selects one by one, then two of them with except.

Comment: Additionally you could add semicolon after last select, I do not remember whether this is needed.

Comment: Maybe MS access doesn't support the except clause or something because both select statements work on their own but once except is added there are errors

Comment: Apparently you are right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980525/access-substitute-for-clause-except

Comment: See also here, maybe it would help you prepare correct query without except: http://p2p.wrox.com/access/55073-minus-except-ms-access.html