# Syntax error in from clause in Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

So I am trying to do this query

```
SELECT * FROM tblIDs
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM tblIDs1
UNION
SELECT * FROM tblIDs1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM tblIDs
```

However this is giving me a syntax error on the from clause.  Is this an issue with Access 2013?
The tables are the exact same and I am looking to see if any of the fields would have a different item in them.  The one thing I know they would have in common is the field ID, past that any of the other fields could be different and thats what I want to see is what is different between the two tables.  If you would like to know the other fields I can provide that but I am trying to avoid that right now.

Comment: I am not aware that MS Access supports `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Access does not support the`EXCEPT`operator. This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980525/access-substitute-for-clause-except

Comment: use left outer join and null check in where clause....MS access not support EXCEPT keyword

Comment: thanks guys! Ill go ahead and do a bunch of OR clauses instead