# UNION does not work in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query that would insert rows from table `temp` into table `DEPENDENT`.  Only rows that are not already in table `DEPENDENT` should be inserted. I have this, and it seems to work on SQL server.  But I keep getting the error "Syntax Error in JOIN operation".  Am I missing something?

```
INSERT INTO DEPENDENT (
 Record_Type,
 Employee_SSN,
 Employee_ID )
SELECT
 unn.Record_Type,
 unn.Employee_SSN,
 unn.Employee_ID
 FROM((
 (SELECT  
    Record_Type,
    Employee_SSN,
    Employee_ID FROM temp) 
        UNION
 (SELECT 
 Record_Type,
 Employee_SSN,
 Employee_ID FROM DEPENDENT))
        EXCEPT 
 (SELECT  
    Record_Type,
    Employee_SSN,
    Employee_ID FROM temp)) AS unn;
```

Also, I know that this is not the most efficient way to do this, but I am just trying to get something working for now.  I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: You have an extra `)` (closing bracket) after `FROM DEPENDENT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access SQL doesn't have `EXCEPT`.

You'll have to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or an outer join.

[Access substitute for clause except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980525/access-substitute-for-clause-except) may help to find a workaround.