# ColdFusion SQL Exclude Results

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I think I need to do an Exception of results.  And not a UNION of results.

The EXCEPT does not work.  Ideas? Using MS Access.

```
  <cfquery name="test" datasource="ds">
     select * from master
     where ( gpslat > #area.bgpslat# and gpslat < #area.tgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.lgpslong# and gpslong < #area.rgpslong# ) 
     and statignore = 0 and eventdate like '%2016%'
       EXCEPT
     select * from master
     where ( gpslat > #area.exbgpslat# and gpslat < #area.extgpslat# ) and ( gpslong > #area.exlgpslong# and gpslong < #area.exrgpslong# )
     and statignore = 0 and eventdate like '%2016%'
   </cfquery>
```

Comment: if you add  a proper data sample and the expetced  result is more easy answer  to you question  .. try explain better

Comment: A google search of `ms access keywords` revealed that you can use `not exists`.  You just have to figure out how.

Comment: You could do a 'not' clause Also see this sample:
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980525/access-substitute-for-clause-except)

Comment: If your `eventdate` is a date, you probably don't want to use `like`. OT: make sure to use `<cfqueryparam>`