# How should I JOIN multiple tables to find what is not in another table in a MS Access SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 4 tables, documents, info, people & reviews. I am trying to write a query that looks at who has not reviewed a document.

Table 'documents' tells me what what documents need to be reviewed.
Table 'info' tells me about each document like who needs to review it.
Table 'people' tells me what type of review each person needs to do.
Table 'reviews' tells me who has reviewed a document and their review details.

My query is:

```
SELECT D.DocNum, I.Name, P.Role, R.ReviewID
FROM (((documents as D 
INNER JOIN info AS I ON D.DocNum = I.DocNum)
INNER JOIN people as P ON I.Name = P.Name)
LEFT JOIN review as R ON D.DocNum = R.DocNum)
WHERE D.DocNum = 1
```

If doc 1 has 5 people to review it, but only 2 people have and 3 that have not, this query will put the two reviews from the two people in each of the 5 people creating 10 rows. If I add a WHERE statement like

```
WHERE R.ReviewID IS NULL
```

I get an empty table.

How should the query look? Thanks.

Comment: I assume `review` also has a field with the ID of the person who's supposed to review the document (maybe `Name`)?  You'll want to join to `review` on that field too: `...LEFT JOIN review as R ON D.DocNum = R.DocNum AND I.Name = R.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use the `EXCEPT` keyword like a union. However, it may not exist in MS Access. It seems as if you have tried the `IS NULL` equivalent, but maybe you haven't set up the `JOIN`s correctly yet. There may be some other things you need to consider in your `WHERE` clause, but without more information about your schema and other requirements, I'm not sure what else we can help with.

> Set Operators - EXCEPT and INTERSECT (Transact-SQL)
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

[Access substitute for EXCEPT clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980525/access-substitute-for-except-clause)

> Can I do an EXCEPT or DIFFERENCE clause in Access?
>   https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=193511

Hopefully the links will help you figure out the issue.